# Directory based error page redirection

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, vhosts

I have my website with two localised content namely EN and FR and the content will be rendered through the URLs: `http://www.example.com/en/` and `http://www.example.com/fr/`

I want to implement different error pages for each of these locale but do not I do not have an idea on how to implement through the redirect/virtual host configuration.

I read about different `.htaccess` file for each of the directory but that did not work.

And help will be good. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @anubhava: They are not actual physical directories, but are proxy to other files in the file system.

Comment: Also tell me your Apache version?

Comment: @anubhava Apache 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having different `.htaccess` works very well, e.g.

```
/-+- en -- .htaccess
  |
  +- fr -- .htaccess
```

And in `/en/.htaccess`, you have

```
ErrorDocument 404 /path/to/en/error404.html
```

and the same with `/fr/.htaccess`

```
ErrorDocument 404 /path/to/fr/error404.html
```

---

You can also put error documents in the same directory and differentiate by extension, e.g. `error404.en.htaml` and `error404.fr.html`. You have then

```
ErrorDocument 404 /path/to/error404.en.html
```

and

```
ErrorDocument 404 /path/to/error404.fr.html
```

respectively.

---

If you don't want to use `.htaccess` files, you can achieve the same with [`Directory`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory) or [`Location`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#location) directives. In your main or virtual host configuration, this would look like

```
<Directory "/path/to/example.com/en">
    ErrorDocument 404 /path/to/error404.en.html
</Directory>

<Directory "/path/to/example.com/fr">
    ErrorDocument 404 /path/to/error404.fr.html
</Directory>
```

The `<Location>` directive looks similar.

Comment: The final approach with the Location directive worked! Thanks @Olaf

Answer (score 0):

On Apache 2.4 you can use expressions:

```
# for /fr/ URIs
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/fr/#">
   ErrorDocument 404 /fr-404.html
</If>

# for /en/ URIs
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/en/#">
   ErrorDocument 404 /en-404.html
</If>
```

[Check Apache 2.4 expression reference](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html).

If you're still stuck with Apache 2.2 then you can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

# for /fr/ URIs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^fr/ /fr-404.html [L]

# for /en/ URIs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^en/ /en-404.html [L]
```

However keep in mind that Apache 2.2 solution will return `200` status to clients.